# Digital timing diagram with google chart using vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, charts, vue.js

I'm trying to render some digital timing diagram using the vuejs framework : 
something like this : 
[image: Digital timing diagram]

The problem is , i've looked at every chart but I can't find a good one to render this.

If someone is familiar with google chart, i'd like to discuss with him
For the moment, i get this : 

[image]

I would like to know if is there any way not to draw simple line between two points ?
Is there a option like curveType that can help me doing what I want ?

Comment: google line chart can handle, what is the issue?

Comment: @WhiteHat My problem is, I don't know how to draw the similar things with my datas.

Comment: check this: https://github.com/drom/wavedrom   

https://codepen.io/imjosh/pen/NjbrVJ

Comment: thank you @imjosh, I saw this solution but I would prefer to stay on google chart library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's all in the data

to keep the chart from connecting the points directly,

you need to repeat values for each change in x or y

this will force all lines to either be drawn vertically or horizontally

repeating the x-axis will result in a vertical line

```
[2, 0],  
[2, 1],  // <-- repeat x-axis to get vertical line (2)
```

repeat y-axis for horizontal

```
[2, 1],  
[4, 1],  // <-- repeat y-axis to get horizontal line (1)
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['bar', 'corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y'],
    [2, 0],  // <-- set start postion
    [2, 1],  // <-- repeat x-axis to get vertical line
    [4, 1],  // <-- repeat y-axis to get horizontal line
    [4, 2],  // <-- vertical
    [5, 2],  // <-- horizontal
    [5, 1],  // <-- vertical
    [6, 1],  // <-- horizontal
    [7, 1],  // <-- horizontal
    [8, 1],
    [8, .5],
    [9, .5],
    [10, .5]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      top: 12,
      right: 12,
      bottom: 24,
      left: 24,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    hAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 12
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 3
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: have never used it but google's [SteppedAreaChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/steppedareachart) may have been a better solution, less data manipulation -- maybe, check it out...